# Field is not writeable: ESR_Assignment__c.Customer_Address1__c at line 95 column 18

Tags: apex, visualforce

when I add formula field then showing like error

```
   /////////control class///////////

public with sharing class importDataFromCSVController {

 public Blob csvFileBody {get;set;}
 public String csvAsString {get;set;}
 public String[] CsvFileLines {get;set;}
 public List < ESR_Assignment__c > camtlist {get;set;}
 public Boolean exprots {get;set;}
 public Map < String, ESR_Assignment__c > esrNoByESR;
 public decimal trno {get;set;}

 public importDataFromCSVController() {
  exprots = False;
  CsvFileLines = new string[] {};
  camtlist = new list < ESR_Assignment__c > ();
  esrNoByESR = new Map < String, ESR_Assignment__c > ();

  for (ESR_Assignment__c objesrs: [select id, Name, ESR_Status__c, Payment__c, Payment_Date__c, Company_Name__c, Difference__c, Customer_Address1__c,CAMT_Payment_Date__c,CAMT_IDNUMBER__c,
                                    CAMT_ESRNumber__c, Total_Amount__c, CAMT_TotalAmount__c, Customer_Name__c,
                                    CAMT_Customer_Name__c, CAMT_CustomerAddress__c,
                                    CAMT_Upload_Date_File__c from ESR_Assignment__c
                                   ]) {

        esrNoByESR.put(objesrs.Name, objesrs);
        esrNoByESR.put(objesrs.CAMT_ESRNumber__c, objesrs);
  }
    system.debug('==33==' + esrNoByESR);
 }

 public void importCSVFile() {
  csvAsString = csvFileBody.toString();
  CsvFileLines = csvAsString.split('\n');
  system.debug('====' + esrNoByESR);
  List < ESR_Assignment__c > upertToList = new List < ESR_Assignment__c > ();

  for (Integer i = 1; i < CsvFileLines.size(); i++) {

   String[] CsvRecordData = CsvFileLines[i].split(',');
   ESR_Assignment__c objesrs = new ESR_Assignment__c();


    String esrnum = (CsvRecordData[1]).trim();

   system.debug('==='+(CsvRecordData[1]).trim());


   Decimal camttotalAmount =0.00;
   if(!String.isEmpty((CsvRecordData[2]).trim())){
       camttotalAmount = decimal.valueof((CsvRecordData[2]).trim());
   }




   ///////////////////////scenario3/////////////

  if (esrNoByESR.keySet() !=Null && esrNoByESR.containsKey(esrnum)){
     objesrs.id = esrNoByESR.get(esrnum).id;
     objesrs.Name = (CsvRecordData[1]);
   //  objesrs.Payment__c=(CsvRecordData[1]);
     //String de = String.valueof(CsvRecordData[0]);
     //system.debug('dedded=' + de);
   // objesrs.CAMT_ESRNumber__c = Decimal.valueof(de.trim());

   /*  objesrs.CAMT_ESRNumber__c =(CsvRecordData[0]);
     objesrs.CAMT_IDNUMBER__c=(CsvRecordData[4]);
     objesrs.CAMT_Payment_Date__c=mydate; */

     //objesrs.Name=objesrs.CAMT_ESRNumber__c;
       // if( objesrs.Status__c == ''){
    // objesrs.Status__c = 'Match';
    // upertToList.add(objesrs);
    // }
         } 

    /*if there is ESR Number is not matched to csv file number this else part will create new esr recordaccordingly */
     else{    
        // objesrs.Name = (CsvRecordData[0]);
        // String de = String.valueof(CsvRecordData[0]);
         //system.debug('dedded=' + de);
        // objesrs.CAMT_ESRNumber_optional__c = Decimal.valueof(de.trim());
       // objesrs.CAMT_ESR_Numberformula_del__c=(CsvRecordData[0]);
          objesrs.CAMT_IDNUMBER__c=(CsvRecordData[0]);
         objesrs.CAMT_ESRNumber__c =(CsvRecordData[1]);
         objesrs.CAMT_TotalAmount__c = camttotalAmount ;
         objesrs.CAMT_Customer_Name__c=(CsvRecordData[3]);
         objesrs.CAMT_CustomerAddress__c=(CsvRecordData[4]);
         objesrs.CAMT_Payment_Date__c=Date.valueof((CsvRecordData[5])); 


         objesrs.ESR_Status__c= 'No Match';
         objesrs.Name='0';
         objesrs.Total_Amount__c=0;
         objesrs.Company_Name__c='Null';
         objesrs.Customer_Name__c='Null';
         objesrs.Customer_Address1__c='Null';
         objesrs.Payment__c=Null;
         objesrs.Difference__c=0; 
       //  upertToList.add(objesrs);
         }

   ////////////////////////secanrio4///////////////////
   if (esrNoByESR.keySet() != Null && esrNoByESR.containsKey(esrnum) && esrNoByESR.get(esrnum).Payment__c == 'Not Paid' && esrNoByESR.get(esrnum).Total_Amount__c == camttotalAmount ) {
    objesrs.id = esrNoByESR.get(esrnum).id;
    objesrs.Name = (CsvRecordData[1]);
    //objesrs.CAMT_ESR_Numberformula__c= camtesrnumber;
    objesrs.CAMT_IDNUMBER__c=(CsvRecordData[0]);
    objesrs.CAMT_ESRNumber__c =(CsvRecordData[1]);
    objesrs.CAMT_TotalAmount__c = camttotalAmount ;
    objesrs.CAMT_Customer_Name__c=(CsvRecordData[3]);
    objesrs.CAMT_CustomerAddress__c=(CsvRecordData[4]);
    objesrs.CAMT_Payment_Date__c=Date.valueof((CsvRecordData[5])); 


    system.debug('esrNoByESR.get(esrnum).Total_Amount__c=' + esrNoByESR.get(esrnum).Total_Amount__c);
    objesrs.Total_Amount__c = esrNoByESR.get(esrnum).Total_Amount__c;
    objesrs.Customer_Name__c = esrNoByESR.get(esrnum).Customer_Name__c;
    objesrs.Difference__c = esrNoByESR.get(esrnum).Difference__c;
    objesrs.Payment__c = esrNoByESR.get(esrnum).Payment__c;
    objesrs.Payment_Date__c = esrNoByESR.get(esrnum).Payment_Date__c;
    objesrs.Company_Name__c = esrNoByESR.get(esrnum).Company_Name__c;
    // objesrs.Customer_Address1__c=esrNoByESR.get(esrnum).Customer_Address1__c;
 //   objesrs.Test__c = Integer.valueof((CsvRecordData[0]).trim());

    objesrs.Payment__c ='Paid';
    objesrs.ESR_Status__c= 'Match';
    objesrs.Difference__c=0;
    upertToList.add(objesrs);
   }

   //////////////////////////secanrio 5/////////////
   else if (esrNoByESR.keySet() != Null && esrNoByESR.containsKey(esrnum) && esrNoByESR.get(esrnum).Payment__c == 'Not Paid' && esrNoByESR.get(esrnum).Total_Amount__c != camttotalAmount ) {


     objesrs.id = esrNoByESR.get(esrnum).id;
     objesrs.Name = (CsvRecordData[1]);
   //  objesrs.Test__c = Integer.valueof((CsvRecordData[0]).trim());

    //objesrs.CAMT_ESR_Numberformula__c= camtesrnumber;
    objesrs.CAMT_IDNUMBER__c=(CsvRecordData[0]);
    objesrs.CAMT_ESRNumber__c =(CsvRecordData[1]);
    objesrs.CAMT_TotalAmount__c = camttotalAmount ;
    objesrs.CAMT_Customer_Name__c=(CsvRecordData[3]);
    objesrs.CAMT_CustomerAddress__c=(CsvRecordData[4]);
    objesrs.CAMT_Payment_Date__c=Date.valueof((CsvRecordData[5])); 

    system.debug('esrNoByESR.get(esrnum).Total_Amount__c=' + esrNoByESR.get(esrnum).Total_Amount__c);
    objesrs.Total_Amount__c = esrNoByESR.get(esrnum).Total_Amount__c;
    objesrs.Customer_Name__c = esrNoByESR.get(esrnum).Customer_Name__c;
    objesrs.Difference__c = esrNoByESR.get(esrnum).Difference__c;
    objesrs.Payment__c = esrNoByESR.get(esrnum).Payment__c;
    objesrs.Payment_Date__c = esrNoByESR.get(esrnum).Payment_Date__c;
    objesrs.Company_Name__c = esrNoByESR.get(esrnum).Company_Name__c;
    system.debug(camttotalAmount+'==='+esrNoByESR.get(esrnum).Total_Amount__c+'===='+(camttotalAmount-esrNoByESR.get(esrnum).Total_Amount__c).toPlainString());
    objesrs.Difference__c=camttotalAmount-esrNoByESR.get(esrnum).Total_Amount__c;
    objesrs.ESR_Status__c= 'Difference';
  //  objesrs.Test__c = Integer.valueof((CsvRecordData[0]).trim());

    upertToList.add(objesrs);

   }

   //////////////////////secanrio 6////////////////////
   /*if there is ESR Number is not matched to csv file number this else part will create new esr recordaccordingly */
   else if (esrNoByESR.keySet() != Null && esrNoByESR.containsKey(esrnum) && esrNoByESR.get(esrnum).Payment__c == 'Paid') {
    objesrs.id = esrNoByESR.get(esrnum).id;
    objesrs.Name = (CsvRecordData[1]);
    //objesrs.CAMT_ESR_Numberformula__c= camtesrnumber;//objesrs.Test__c = Integer.valueof((CsvRecordData[0]).trim());
    objesrs.CAMT_IDNUMBER__c=(CsvRecordData[0]);
    objesrs.CAMT_ESRNumber__c =(CsvRecordData[1]);
    objesrs.CAMT_TotalAmount__c = camttotalAmount;
    objesrs.CAMT_Customer_Name__c=(CsvRecordData[3]);
    objesrs.CAMT_CustomerAddress__c=(CsvRecordData[4]);
    objesrs.CAMT_Payment_Date__c=Date.valueof((CsvRecordData[5]));  


    system.debug('esrNoByESR.get(esrnum).Total_Amount__c=' + esrNoByESR.get(esrnum).Total_Amount__c);
    objesrs.Total_Amount__c = esrNoByESR.get(esrnum).Total_Amount__c;
    objesrs.Customer_Name__c = esrNoByESR.get(esrnum).Customer_Name__c;
    objesrs.Difference__c = esrNoByESR.get(esrnum).Difference__c;
    objesrs.Payment__c = esrNoByESR.get(esrnum).Payment__c;
    objesrs.Payment_Date__c = esrNoByESR.get(esrnum).Payment_Date__c;
    objesrs.Company_Name__c = esrNoByESR.get(esrnum).Company_Name__c;


    objesrs.ESR_Status__c= 'Already Match';
    objesrs.Difference__c=0;
    upertToList.add(objesrs);
   }



   camtlist.add(objesrs);
  }


  system.debug('list==' + camtlist);
 // try{
  system.debug('coming' + upertToList);
  if (camtlist.size() > 0)
   update upertToList;
  system.debug('going out ' + upertToList);
 //  }     
  /* Catch(Exception e){

    Apexpages.Message errorMessage =new Apexpages.Message(Apexpages.severity.ERROR,'An error is occured when importing data Please make sure input csv file is correct');

   Apexpages.AddMessage(errorMessage );
   }
   */
  // return null;
 }


 public PageReference  ExcelFileDownload() {

  exprots = true;
  return null;
 }

}
```

//////////////////visualforce page////////////

```
<script>
    function refersh(){
        var url = window.location.href;
        window.location = url;
    }
</script>

<apex:form >
    <apex:pagemessages />
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="4" > 
              <apex:inputFile value="{!csvFileBody}"  filename="{!csvAsString}"/>
              <apex:commandButton value="Import CAMT File" action="{!importCSVFile}" rendered="{!camtlist.size!=Null}" disabled="{!IF((camtlist.size>0 ), true, false)}"/>
            <!--<apex:commandButton value="Download Excel" action="{!ExcelFileDownload}" /> -->
      </apex:pageBlockSection>
       <apex:outputText value="{!trno}"></apex:outputText>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlock rendered="{!camtlist.size>0}">
       <apex:pageblocktable value="{!camtlist}" var="cam">

            <!--- CAMT File Uploaded --->
         <!---  <apex:column value="{!cam.Name}" headerValue="ESR Number"/>
           <apex:column value="{!cam.CAMT_ESRNumber_optional__c}" headerValue="CAMT ESR Number"/>
           <apex:column value="{!cam.Status__c}" headerValue="CAMT Status"/>  --->

         <apex:column value="{!cam.CAMT_IDNUMBER__c  }" headerValue="CAMT ESR ID"/>
       <!--- <apex:column value="{!cam.CAMT_ESR_Numberformula_del__c}" headerValue="CAMT ESR ID"/> --->
         <apex:column value="{!cam.CAMT_ESRNumber__c}" headerValue="CAMT ESRNUmber"/>
          <apex:column value="{!cam.CAMT_TotalAmount__c}" headerValue="CAMT Total Amount"/>
          <apex:column value="{!cam.CAMT_Customer_Name__c}" headerValue="CAMT Customer Name"/>
          <apex:column value="{!cam.CAMT_CustomerAddress__c}" headerValue="CAMT Customer Address" /> 
           <apex:column value="{!cam.CAMT_Payment_Date__c}" headerValue="CAMT Payment Date"/>

         <!--- <apex:column value="{!cam.CAMT_Upload_Date_File__c}" headerValue="CAMT:Upload Date File" />--------->
         <!---<apex:column value="{!cam.CAMT_Payment__c}" headerValue="CAMT:CAMT Payment" />--->
         <!--- <apex:column value="{!cam.CAMT_CustomerAddress__c}" headerValue="CAMT Customer Address" /> --->


          <!---- Fetch Data From Data Base --->

         <apex:column value="{!cam.ESR_Status__c}" headerValue="Process Match" />
          <apex:column value="{!cam.Name}"  headerValue="ESRNumber"/>
          <apex:column value="{!cam.Total_Amount__c}" headerValue="Total Amount"/>
          <apex:column value="{!cam.Customer_Name__c}" headerValue="Customer Name"/>
          <apex:column value="{!cam.Customer_Address1__c}" headerValue="Customer Address" />
        <apex:column value="{!cam.Company_Name__c}" headerValue="Company Name" />
         <apex:column value="{!cam.Payment__c}" headerValue="Payment" /> 
          <apex:column value="{!cam.Payment_Date__c}" headerValue="Payment Date" /> 
          <apex:column value="{!cam.Difference__c}" headerValue="Difference" /> 

         <!--- <apex:column headerValue="Adress">

          <apex:outputText value="{!cam.Customer_Address1__c}">
          </apex:outputText> 
          </apex:column>  --->

    </apex:pageblocktable>

        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:actionregion >
                <apex:commandButton value="Download Excel" action="{!ExcelFileDownload}" rendered="{!camtlist.size>0}" />
                <input type="button" class="btn" value="Clear" onclick="refersh();" style="{!IF((camtlist.size>0 ), '', 'display:none')}"/>
            </apex:actionregion>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
 </apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: is Customer_Address1__c a formula field? Formula fields cant be assigned a value and hence the error

Comment: yes Customer_Address1__c is formula field.